# Required validation on ui-select multiselect dropdown using xtForm

Tags: angularjs, validation, dropdown, ui-select

I am using "[ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)" library for custom dropdowns and [xtForm](https://github.com/refactorthis/xtform) library for validations. How can I do **required** validation of multiselect dropdown using xtForm?

For the time being, I am using following code for validation:

```
<ui-select name="emailTo" ng-style='addReport.emailTo.$valid?{"border":"1px solid #ccc"}:{"border":"1px solid red"}' ui-select-required multiple
        data-ng-disabled="isControlDisabled" data-ng-model="currentReport.emailToTemp" theme="bootstrap" data-ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;min-height:34px">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.key}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="person.value as person in people | propsFilter: {key: $select.search}">
      <div data-ng-bind-html="person.key | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.value}}
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

But it has two drawbacks:
1) the dropdown's border is red when the form loads for the very first time.
2) it does not show tooltip like that using xtForm for other controls.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `ng-style` attribute from `ui-select` tag. Since `ng-style` is applying the red border when the field is invalid.

After referring the documentation of xtform, I think you need to assign an `id` to `ui-select` element and use it in `xt-validation-inline`.

```
<ui-select name="emailTo" id="selectPerson" ui-select-required multiple data-ng-disabled="isControlDisabled" data-ng-model="currentReport.emailToTemp" theme="bootstrap" data-ng-disabled="disabled"
style="width: 100%;min-height:34px">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select person...">{{$item.key}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person.value as person in people | propsFilter: {key: $select.search}">
    <div data-ng-bind-html="person.key | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <small>
            email: {{person.value}}
          </small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<xt-validation-inline for="selectPerson"></xt-validation-inline>
```

Also, If you want to show the validation messages only on form submit, You can add strategy to your form with value `submitted`

```
<form strategy="submitted">
    ...
</form>
```

This will cause the validation messages & styling to be shown only on form submit.